# Data explorer: votes without voters

Tags: support, data-explorer

Hi,

It seems that the vast majority of the votes has no `userid` associated with it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE userid IS NULL;     -- Nobody voted?
9211783

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE userid IS NOT NULL;​
674035
```

Am I missing something? I thought that every vote must have a voter behind it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They do have voters behind them...but that data isn't exported.  If you look at the ones that *do* have a `userid`, you'll see they're all VoteTypeId `5`:

```
SELECT Distinct(VoteTypeId) FROM votes WHERE userid IS NOT NULL;​
```

`5` is a favorite vote...that's the only type of data exposed, all other votes are made anonymous as part of the data export...hopefully for obvious reasons :)

---

Perhaps [a query like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/16682/) makes a bit clearer illustration:

```
SELECT Name, 
       Count(*) TotalVotes, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) TotalWithUserId
FROM Votes Inner Join VoteTypes ON VoteTypeId = VoteTypes.Id
GROUP BY Name​
```

Results as of this answer:

```
Name                    TotalVotes     TotalVotesWithUserId
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AcceptedByOriginator    705584          0
BountyClose             12157           0
BountyStart             12342           0
Close                   2666            0
Deletion                270428          0
DownMod                 546646          0
Favorite                674035          674035
Offensive               700             0
Reopen                  56              0
Spam                    1763            0
Undeletion              19541           0
UpMod                   7639900         0
```

Comment: Seems user IDs are now exported for votes of type 8 (bounty start) as well.