# Make Data Explorer know my votes

Tags: support, data-explorer

As noted [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72707/data-explorer-votes-without-voters) the userid doesn't tell you who made the vote unless it's a favorite vote (type 5.)

By what mechanism can we use the Data Explorer to count our votes, say for electorate progress? Also, what is the reasoning behind only populating userid on the favorite type?

Thanks!

Comment: To answer the latter point - favorites are public info. If I look at your profile, I can see what questions you have marked as a favorite. I cannot see what questions you have voted on, because those are anonymous. That's why it's currently only populated for the favorite type, because that's the one that is publicly accessible.

Comment: @Grace I guess that's a reasonable concern. I'm not sure it should be anonymous to me as well, although to do otherwise would require two sets of data: one public, one private. Is that an undesirable scenario?

Comment: This is no longer an issue as this information is now reported in your profile. Yay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By what mechanism can we use the Data Explorer to count our votes, say for electorate progress?

It can only be approximated, because the data needed literally *does not exist* in the system.

> I'm not sure it should be anonymous to me as well

Agreed, I would like to see this, too!

However, the complexity of implementing such a thing right now isn't feasible. Perhaps in the future.

Currently, Data Explorer's data source *is* the publicly available data dump, which has anonymized votes for everyone.

To make it such that the system knows *it's you* logged in isn't *that* difficult to implement, but doing data retrieval while maintaining security of confidential data would add a lot of moving parts -- the anonymity of other users' confidential data must be maintained above all other concerns, so the simpler the better. Such a solution would require views of a database that necessarily has confidential data -- this is asking for trouble, saying nothing of storage and performance requirements/availability.

So, yes, I could maybe see this implemented down the road, but right now I'd say it's pretty much out of the question, or at least a very very low priority from a business perspective.

Answer (score 2):

For the Electorate badge, just use `Users.upvotes + Users.downvotes`.

> Will this filter between question votes and answer votes though

No it won't.  Vote this up [Can we add vote history to the data.se dumps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80310/156011)

Comment: Will this filter between question votes and answer votes though?

Comment: @glowcoder answer updated