# Find posts I upvoted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, search

Is there a possibility to search for postings which I already upvoted and use keywords/tags for this search? If not, should this be made possible?

I will explain why I want this:

We are able to find all questions/answers we have voted on (like Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan pointed out). I am voting for good posts frequently and as a beginner I read new and helpful information all the time. Because I want to use those helpful posts in the future I would like to have the possibility to find them faster using keywords and tags. Say I know I already read a good post about parsing columns with awk and very likely upvoted it, I want to read it again.

As ProgramFOX said it is possible to do this search for questions I marked as a favorite. The point is that I don't want to favorite all those questions leading in hundreds or thousands of favorites. With doing so there wouldn't be any difference in voting and setting favorites. There wouldn't be the need to vote anything at all. At least for me.

To sum it up: Ideally I would like to use an additional searching flag which states, that I already upvoted (maybe to make it consistent for downvotes and others too). This could look like:

```
"search term here" inupvoted:mine
```

I hope others will think similarly and the admins could think about adding this feature.

Comment: Why would you want to find posts you've already upvoted? (And note that voting is anonymous, so finding out votes from others is not going to be possible).

Comment: Voting is anonymous. You can't see who voted (other than your own votes cast) at all. Your own votes are indicated by the appearance of the voting arrows (the ones you've clicked are highlighted). They are not visible to others (or searchable) by design.

Comment: @Bart why not? Ofc because I did like those postings and want to read them again. And it's not very unlikely that I know I already read a good solution here and upvoted it. So I want to find those quality posts faster with this option of filtering. And is your edit really necessary?...

Comment: @bashophil You can already favourite questions by clicking on the star next to them. And with regards to my edit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @Ken White I understand this. Why not allow this option for my own votings then?

Comment: Seems like a search operator like this would put quite a heavy load on the server. Votes are not directly connected to the post. So consider a user having 10,000 upvotes - you would first have to search the Votes table to find all those upvotes, then you'd have to search through the Posts table one by one compiling a list of every post that those votes match up to, and *then* search through all those posts for your other search criteria. That doesn't seem like a very plausible search option.

Comment: @animuson There are more answers than questions, but there shoudn't be a major difference for the `infavorites:mine` flag. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to see the posts which you have upvoted, go to your profile, go to the votes tab and select **upvotes**.

If you mean you want to search posts you upvoted through the search box, then this is not (yet) possible. If you really want to find back questions you like, then add them as a favorite, and then you can search for your favorites like this:

> "search term here" infavorites:mine

<s>If you're good at SQL, then you can try to compose a query at the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to search for posts that you upvoted.</s>
I'm sorry, I was wrong about this (see the comments of Bart). The Data Explorer doesn't expose upvote and downvote information, but information such as favorites, close votes, bounties, ...

Comment: I know this, but would like to do a search for a term and this solely for my upvoted postings. I don't want to use hundreds of favorite questions. I favorite questions just if they are really special.

Comment: If you're good at SQL, then you can try to compose a query at Data.SE. I updated my answer.

Comment: Where is ben when we need him? :)

Comment: @ProgramFOX The data explorer doesn't expose voting information, so how would that help?

Comment: @Bart: There's a "Votes" table.

Comment: And what does that contain @ProgramFOX?

Comment: @Bart: That table contains a 'UserId' column and a 'PostId' column. It contains more columns, but these columns are the most important.

Comment: @ProgramFOX have a look at those columns and what they contain. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72707/data-explorer-votes-without-voters

Comment: @Bart: You're right, it doesn't expose up/downvote info. I've just tried it out and I got my favorite questions and my offered bounty, but not my up/downvotes. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Exactly. All the non-public information is removed before the data is made available. Otherwise the whole "votes are anonymous" idea would go out the window, wouldn't it? ;)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a function for that!

If you go to your profile and click on Votes; that is just to the bottom right side of your profile page. There you will see the votes that were casted by you. You can select votes from the navigation menu; its the last item.

The following is the result from the page which shows the type of the votes being casted by and the type of the vote too. And a filter for the results.

[image]

I am sorry, the image was caught from Stackoverflow, but it is just the same for meta too. And it will show you upotes, downvotes, deletion and all other types of votes. You can see the filter on the top right side! So I guess that was the link you wanted to know about.

However searching for a question that you have voted and has a certain tag is now currently allowed. I hope it will soon be allowed too, but I am not sure whether that would happen or not, a moderator would help you in this situation. But currently you can search either for tags that you have answered for, or the votes that you have casted!

Comment: Sorry for my imprecise question but this isn't what I was looking for. Nonetheless your last passage is exactly what I was trying to ask and what I would like to be implemented on SE.

Comment: Yes, you're right! The last passage describes the problem that you're facing. However its still not allowed, you can hope that SE would allow this too :) You have suggested it, they will look into it :)

Comment: Thx mate. So at least we are two who would like to use such a feature. I also edited the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is currently unavailable. You need to either search for tags that you have answered or you can search for the voting activity from your account.

There are some general menus that you can use and surf the account profile. Let's hope we get such functions soon.